# CSS - Center <p> in the div but with text aligned to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I saw answers here that show how to center a `<p>` with a center-aligned text. But how do I center the `<p>` with the text aligned to the left? I need it for the poetry site, so I cant center my text.

I want it to look like so :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the text in a container (called `poemtext` in my example). This container, you make `display: inline-block` to make it a block that fits snugly around the text, and which can be centered inside the parent. With a bit of extra markup, you can center the poemtext, and make sure it automatically breaks on line breaks.

Note that the `>` of the opening tag of the poemtext will have to be on the same line as the first line of the poem, otherwise you'll get an extra white line leading the poem.

```css
.poem {
  text-align: center;
}

.poemtext {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-line;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="poem">
  <div class="poemtext"
  > Roses are red
    Violets are blue
    All my base are belong to you
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```css
.my-block {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.my-article {
    margin: 0 20%;
 }

.my-article p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-block">
    <div class="my-article">
        <p>This is my first paragraph. It is explicitly left-aligned even though the default it inherits from it's parent is the same. It's good to be crystal clear, just in case the parent changes later in the game.</p>
      
        <p>This is paragraph two. The same rules apply. And as you can see these two paragraphs are centered even though there's nothing about centering in the CSS rules!! It's a trick with the margins of the inner div.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Margins leading instead of text width leading. Another way to tackle this problem, and very useful for displaying text that isn't `pre` formatted. You actually only need the margin on the parent. `text-align: left` is probably default. Good answer.